# C++: Auto-interrupt a getch() call

Tags: c++, multithreading, input, io

## Problem

My program has multiple threads, with two currently important ones; The "Keyboard" thread is a `getch()` call wrapped by a while loop, and the "Conductor" thread imitates a user's input on a schedule for automation purposes. I need to find a way for the Conductor to interrupt the Keyboard thread without any intervention from the user.

## Solutions

I have a couple of strategies that I anticipate the answer may take the form of.

### A: A timed `getch()` call

I wonder if it may be possible to have the `getch()` call timeout after some time and continue execution of the program without any input from user.  This would allow the loop to check for input from the user for some amount of time, and then check for input from the Conductor (which would otherwise not be able to communicate with the Keyboard thread because the `getch()` call would still be running).  This could leave a potential bug in the program, if the user happens to hit the keyboard while the Keyboard thread isn't listening via `getch()`, but it would be one solution.

### B: Insert data into input stream

It may be possible for the Conductor to send information to the Keyboard thread by using the input stream that `getch()` uses.  I know very little about the specifics of `getch()` and input-output in general, but I think that there must be some way for the Conductor to imitate the user's keyboard and send a key that will be picked up by `getch()`.  If possible, this would be the preferred solution (no foreseeable bugs, and would simplify the design of the Conductor).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Must be Windows/DOS; there is no `getch()` call in Linux.

Comment: Console or windowing application?  Windowing applications send notification when a key is pressed.  With a console application, you will need an API to check if a key is pressed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It may be considered a windowing application, because it does create a graph (using GLUT), though most interaction is through the console.  `getch()` already checks for a key press.  Are you suggesting using a new function to check for a key press?  Can some other function like that be interrupted by my Conductor?